# Exception handling: writing my own class if no one fit, even if I just need the basic functionality?

Tags: java, exception

I've always been told to reuse the exception provided in Java, especially if I don't need to add any new functionality to the exception class.

In my case I've some check classes that check the health of the system, and I need to throw an exception if something isn't working. I just need to set an error message that any exception class provide. The fact is that I can't really find one class that fit the purpose.

What do you suggest me to do?

Use the base class Exception?
Writing my own class anyway?

Comment: I would use `RuntimeException`.

Comment: It's not a unchecked exception, Marko, because it's not a programming mistake. The program need to generate an exception if something on the system is not as expected, so it's a checked exception.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a programming mistake, but what you actually do with it in the program. If you catch it close to where you throw it, then you can live with a checked exception; otherwise it only creates problems like interface mismatches, leaky abstractions, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your own class if nothing else fits.

The sub-classes of Exception are just to filter in a catch clause, they serve no other purpose (think of them more like a switch/case). So if the filters you currently have are not sufficient, just write a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I often override the Exception class with the purpose of having a global exception handler handle it differently from other exceptions with `instance of`. IMHO it's also much more readable than having to look inside the exception to see what's going on.

Comment: You have to look inside anyway because the stack trace is what really matters.